# Ng-repeat с последнего индекса

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Не могу реализовать ng-repeat с лимитом до числа n, потом снова сделать ng-repeat уже с остановившегося (последнего) индекса n. Пример:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
    <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo : 3"></td>

    </tr>
        <!-- а дальше уже продолжить с последнего места, т.е. уже со 2го индекса -->
    <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo : 3"></td>

   </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

(Исправлено)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать slice из обычного JS:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items.slice(0, 3)">
    ...
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items.slice(3)">
    ...
</tr>
```

Но лучше расскажите, зачем вам это, так как вы хотите чего-то странного.

Comment: У меня не получается перенести <td> во вторую строку (tr), понимаете, в чем фишка? В каждом <tr> три <td> и не больше) сейчас попробую Ваш метод)

Comment: Тоесть вы хотите разбить массив произвольной длины в строки по три ячейки?

Comment: да, все верно)

Comment: Так у вас ничего хорошего не выйдет. Вам нужно еще в контроллере разбить свой массив на группы по 3 штуки и в шаблоне выводить уже их. Например, так: http://jsfiddle.net/b5h9txwm/4/